# why does a script take long to run than a normal terminal command?

Tags: unix, time, tcsh

So i wrote a very dumb script

```
#!/bin/env tcsh

ls-F --color=always -h
```

and saved it as `test.csh`

Now when i `time` the same command and the script this is what i see

```
time ~/scripts/bin/test.csh 
....
Elapsed:0:04.63,User=3.733,System=0.329,CPU=87.4%.
```

and if i run the command in terminal

```
time ls-F --color=always -h
....
Elapsed:0:00.00,User=0.000,System=0.000,CPU=0.0%
```

I dont understand the internal working of the kernel/scheduler, I am just trying to understand what causes this delay

I am using

```
RHEL5 x86_64
```

`tcsh` as my shell

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you run a script, it is creating and initializing a new environment, referencing dot files, scripts, etc.

When you run a terminal command, it is running in an established environment and no initialization needs to occur.

You can see the extra processes going on with an `strace`

Try running `strace text.sh 2>&1 | tee out_script.txt` and `strace ls-F --color=always -h 2>&1 | tee out_noscript.txt`

Then you can diff or compare the two files to see the additional steps required to set up a new environment.

Comment: `ls-F` is a tcsh builtin, so it can't be straced. Although it probably just execs the real `ls` when it sees an argument like `--color` that it can't handle

Comment: Good point.  In either case though this should apply with any other command (I believe the ls was merely an example of a basic command).

Comment: @Alec is it possible to tell the script to run on the established environment instead of creating a new environment?

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is the `source` command.  You could run the script with `source test.csh` or `. test.csh` which I *believe* has the desired effect of running the commands within the current shell.  This also lets you set env variables and such within the current shell rather than as a sub shell.  But this may not be 100%.  The timing seems to reflect that though.

Comment: In double checking, yes.  It runs the files in the current context rather than as a separate env.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command)